# Finding a tag / multiple tags across multiple documents

Tags: machine-learning, python, natural-language, named-entity-recognition

Suppose we have text documents:

```
doc1 = 'Legal research is the process of finding information that is needed to support legal decision-making. In practice, this generally means searching through both statute (as created by the legislature) and case law (as developed by the courts) to find what is relevant for some specific matter at hand.'

doc2 = 'Machine learning (ML) is a type of artificial intelligence (AI) that allows software applications to become more accurate at finding an information without being explicitly programmed to do so. Machine learning algorithms use historical data as input to predict new output values.'
```

I wish to define a tag in this case `tag = 'finding information'`, now I would like to make a model that can go through my documents and find the tag (or ideally tags). At first one might say, on each document I can perform a brute search. However, as you can see from above in doc2 I have: 'finding an information' so the brute search won't work due to having `an` in the middle. I also wonder how one split the data into train and test, this is because in the training part there is no label (for the tag).

This problem looks like named entity recognition but my search shows that NER just returns bunch predefined entities such as person, location and etc. I wonder if there are models out there that can handle cases like mine? Maybe NER is not what I should look into. Any model implementation or source would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like the "model" you're looking for is just the ability to search a document for 2 words and then determine if there's 0 or 1 words between those 2 words. This seems like a regex.

Comment: As explained the tags are not always 2 words, they can be phrases and I need the search to be such that if some other words come within the given tag, I would be able to highlight it. Can regex do this?

Comment: If you don't want to use regex, just return all documents containing the desired words and sort by distance between them. The documents with the shortest distance between the words are higher quality. This doesn't seem to be a statistical question.

Comment: @Sycorax this sounds like a nice approach, is there any implementation/example of it out there?